# How to get CDI in war AND EJB running if both are bundled in an EAR

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi, ear, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to build an enterprise application which is assembled in an EAR. This application should contain one or more *ejb-jars* and one or more *war*'s. I want to make heavily use of *CDI*, Interceptors and Producers. In the first step I want to use a *Log-Producer* which is placed in the *ejb-jar* in all areas of the application.

What I did is creating a beans.xml in the ejb/META-INF and the war/WEB-INF/ folders. Creating the EAR works. But deploying to the Glassfish Server (3.1) fails with a ClassNotFoundException of the Interceptor Class which is placed in the *ejb-jar*.

Removing the EAR and deploying the *ejb-jar* inside the *war* works as expected.

Due the reason of modularisation and the fact of having more *war*'s and *ejb-jar*'s a deployment based on an *EAR* is highly welcome.

So the question is: Is there a way to create a full featured EAR including CDI and all other nice stuff?

Thank you very much.

Cheers
Ansgar

Answer (score 1):

We had similar problems with CDI on JBoss 6. The [workaround](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UseJBossWebClassLoaderInJBoss5) for us was to configure the WAR deployer to use one global class loader scope togteher with the other applications deployed in the EAR file. By default each application in a WAR file uses its own class loader scope. Unfortunately I don't know whether there is a similar configuration available for Glassfish, but I guess there is.

There is an open [ticket](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17396) on the glassfish issue tracker, which might to relate to your problem as well.