# How to use local @EJB-annotation between WAR and JAR in EAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm using a JBoss eap 6.4 and tries to create a test EAR with a WAR and a JAR with ejb's inside.

My problem is that Servlets in my WAR can not make local calls (@EJB) to the ejb's inside the JAR even though they are packed inside the same EAR. The reference is never injected.

I found this for local clients: *It must run in the same application as the enterprise bean it accesses.* at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html#girfl. To my that sounds like my situation, please correct me if I'm wrong.

I also found this interesting post:
[EAR vs separate EJB + WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968587/ear-vs-separate-ejb-war/6969520#6969520). To me the situation #1 in the first answer sounds like this should work.

But I also found this post: [How to get CDI in war AND EJB running if both are bundled in an EAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914478/how-to-get-cdi-in-war-and-ejb-running-if-both-are-bundled-in-an-ear?rq=1) that saying that there is different scope for the classloader. To me that sounds like my attempt with local calls **never** will work. Could it be different situation's for different app-servers?

To illustrate this I just made this image, the problem is where the red arrow is.

Do you think I have mixed something up?

[image: Image of my EAR]

Best regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` into `ear META-INF` directory.

see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.2/html/development_guide/chap-class_loading_and_modules

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your coment, really interesting page. If I get it right it each WAR, JAR etc inside a EAR is a isolated module then? But on the first page I referred to above it say that it should be possible to use the  java:app namespace is used to look up local enterprise beans packaged within the same application. Should I not be able to to that with @EJB then?

Comment: Since you are using JBoss EAP what about asking Redhead this question?

Comment: Hello! I actually have done that already: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/276413, but no answers.

Comment: I just mention that it looks like the forum where I posted the question is EOL. Instead it looks like I should post them here but with tag "jboss-eap-6". So I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448804/how-to-use-ejb-in-this-local-context-with-jboss-6-4

Comment: Just mention that I solved it in the new post, best regards.